# What is the pivot-like in Windows Store Application?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-store-apps, pivot, win-universal-app

i'm making a universal app for Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 and i'd like to know what is the control in a windows app which work like the PIVOT in WP.

I found this picture in the msdn site http://assets.windowsphone.com/ec9dcbf2-d057-4d2d-a627-01565d2ff76a/WSA_Design_L2_1_UniquelyWindows_ModernDesign_702x394px_InvariantCulture_Default.jpg

on the picture you can see a menu on top, i imagine that if you click on "Timer", the main screen would slide to the left to make room for the main screen for "Timer". 
It's the most pivot-like that i found but i don't know what is used to do that.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english, hard to find the right words when you don't know how it's called >< !

Comment: You can do something a bit similar to this with a FlipView. Though I'd bet it's a custom control that's basically some navigation buttons on top of a Frame that just navigates between each view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a direct equivalent. The point of the pivot is to break up the UI into phone screen-sized parts; you don't needs this so much on the tablet/PC.

The hub app template is the closest starting point, but really you should probably design your app as if all the pivots are open at once and spread out horizontally.

Use a grid control with several more sub-grids within it. Or you may want to redesign your layout completely for larger screens. You'll need to put the controls within a scrollviewer in order to let the user scroll left/right on screens that won't fit it all at once.

Comment: Thanks ! It's a shame that Universal App can't have really the same code. My Pivot screen can't be open and spread out, it'll be weird in my case. I think i'll design the app differently than on WP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FlipView control and place grids in it. It's not same as Pivot though, putting title on page items like PivotHeaders will be a little harder. But still there is almost a work around.